# Limit notation causes leaders not followed by proper glue error

Tags: errors, nath

I am a beginner at Latex, and I am trying to learn it to use for my math courses. Following is a minimal example of what's causing the problem. This works fine without Nath, but I want Nath to get better parentheses, among other things.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T \to \infty} T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there another notation for limits when using Nath that I'm not aware of? If so, I can't seem to find any references of that in the Nath documentation.

Comment: If you are a beginner (or even if not) I'd use normal latex math markup rather than `nath` it makes any expressions you use far more portable and usable.

Comment: Well yes, generally I agree with you that as a beginner it's best to stick to the defaults, but I think typing alot of \left(, \right) obfuscates the source code in such a degree that it's really hard to know where I am in my mathematical expressions.

Comment: It seems that the error is caused by `\to`; no error if `\rightarrow` is used. My advice is to consider `nath` as just an interesting attempt that's unfortunately incompatible with most packages.

Comment: Maybe you should start with _plain_ math environment, and later maybe use `amsmath` e.g. that improves and ease many things (included parenthesis). I never used `nath` so I can't say a thing about it.

Comment: redefining _everything_  to avoid typing `\left` is brave though, you should rarely need it anyway, just use suitable environments or commands that add it, eg using `pmatrix` rather than `matrix` not only adds `\left( \right)` it further fine tunes the spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, doesn't using matrices for styling purposes defeat the purpose of Tex's separation of structure and style?

Comment: No, I meant that as an example (if you want matrices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to compile an example in `nath` documentation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
$$
A \to^f_{\text{isomorphism}} B, \qquad a \mapsto^f a’
$$
\end{document}
```

and, while the output is as expected, LaTeX stops with the error message

```
! Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
                   \mskip 
l.6 A \to^f_{\text{isomorphism}} B
                                  , \qquad a \mapsto^f a’
?
```

In order to be sure that possible recent changes have spoiled `nath`, I typeset the code using TeX Live 2009.

The conclusion is that `\to` is buggy. The same is for `\ot`, `\otto` and `\mapsto`. Maybe the bug can be fixed, but `nath` seems to be undeveloped since 2003.

Using `\rightarrow` is safe.

I can't recommend using `nath`. It's incompatible with several packages and offers much less than `amsmath`.

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in `nath.sty` in the definition of `\axis@@`, which occurs in the definition of `\longrightarrow@` which is invoked by `\to` (and other commands, including `\mapsto`). Here is what that definition is:

```
\def\axis@@{\mkern-4.5mu    %%% mkern setting adjusted 24 Sept. 2002
 \axis@@@\mskip 3mu plus \arrow@expandability mu   %%% thanks to E.H. Lohse
 \mkern-4.5mu}
```

The error is that `\axis@@@` should be followed by `\hfill`, so here is what it should be:

```
\def\axis@@{\mkern-4.5mu    %%% mkern setting adjusted 24 Sept. 2002
 \axis@@@\hfill\mskip 3mu plus \arrow@expandability mu   %%% thanks to E.H. Lohse
 \mkern-4.5mu}
```

The added `\hfill` supplies "proper glue". When it is not present, the `\cleaders` command invoked by `\axis@@@` sees an `\mskip` command, which is "improper glue".